# How to get length of a char array, so that valgrind is happy

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this constructor from my custom string class ( for homework ) that receives char array as parameter. Then each time it receives a char array like this one: "Hello", valgrind reports "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value", but the programme still works correctly. I tried several ways of taking the length and still got this problem. So is there a correct way to get the length of char array like the one I mentioned above, without valgrind having problems with it?

```
CString::CString ( const char * charArray )
{
  index = 0;
  arrAlocated = 0;
  string = nullptr;
  int length = strlen ( charArray );


  for ( index = 0; index < length; ++index )
  {
    if ( index == arrAlocated )
    {
      realloc ( string, index, arrAlocated );
    }
    string [ index ] = charArray [ index ];
  }
  string [ index ] = 0;
}
```

This is the class declaration.

```
class CString
{
public:

  int arrAlocated;
  int index;
  char * string;

      CString ( );

      CString ( const char * array);

      CString ( const CString & other );

      ~CString ( );

      void clear ( );

      CString & operator = ( const CString & other );

      bool operator == ( const CString & other ) const;


      char operator [] ( int i ) const
      {
        return string[ i ];
      }

      void realloc ( char *& string, int index, int & arrAlocated );

      int length ( )
      {
        return strlen ( string );
      }

      friend ostream & operator << ( ostream & os, const CString & o )
      {
        for ( int i = 0; i < o.index; ++i )
        {
          os << o.string [ i ];
        }
        return os;
      }
};
```

And here is my realloc function

```
void CString::realloc ( char *& string, int index, int & arrAlocated )
{
  arrAlocated += 10;
  arrAlocated *= 2;

  char * newArray = new char [ arrAlocated ];

  for ( int i = 0; i < index; ++i )
  {
    newArray [ i ] = string [ i ];
  }
  delete [] string;
  string = newArray;
}
```

Comment: Which of your methods/variables are members of `CString`, and which are not?

Comment: I just edited it, now you can see the class.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't assigning the return value of realloc.  string remains null the entire time.

(Also, you know the size you'll need to start from the beginning.  Just call malloc once.)

Comment: Yeah, realloc is my function aswell. The only problem I have is with the length of the array. The rest should work fine

Comment: Just pass the array size as an argument. Arrays have no way to retrieve their size. You can get the size of a stack allocated or global storage array as long as its definition is visible from the current scope by using `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`, but that's not an option for arrays passed as arguments.